# Condition IF isnt working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

In this code, im comparing if the anchor clicked have a different rel attribute string in comparison to the form's id string.

```
$('.title a').each(function(i){
    $('.title a:eq('+i+')').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.title a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var rel     = $(this).attr('rel'),
            formId  = $('form').attr('id');

        if (formId!=rel) {
            $('form[id!='+rel+']').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('form[id='+rel+']').fadeIn(200);
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

the first time i click, it works well. But if i click again it wont work and i cant find the problem, can someone help me?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4MMw/

Comment: why `each`, you could have done that with `$(this)`?

Comment: Firstly, your each loop seems useless. Secondly, could you post relevant HTML code and provide a jsfiddle

Comment: coz theres more than one anchor

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in there (using developer tools/firebug) and see what it is actually comparing the second time you click it.

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos anyway, jquery already iterate through matched set elements

Comment: doesn't matter, click event would bind it to every element

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos `$('.title a').click(...)` will attach a listener to each anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$('.title a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.title a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

  $('form#' + rel).fadeIn(200, function(){
    $('form:not(#' + rel + ')').fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

I've inverted fades, so if there is a form with given ID, it will fadeId, otherwise othing will happen.

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos If you find my answer correct, remember to accept it.